# Not calling MainActivity first, calling another activity in android

Tags: android, multithreading

I am making an application in which I have to show a welcome page for only 5 seconds and then redirect to another activity.  However, I am not getting what I want because I am getting another activity first and MainActivity after click on the back button of the emulator which is not right.  So could somebody please help me?

I am placing some code for your reference specially welcome activity and manifest code:

```
 public class Welcome extends Activity   
 {  
    private Runnable runnable;  
    private static final String TAG="Welcome";  

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */  
    @Override  
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)   
    {  
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
        setContentView(R.layout.main);  

        runnable=new Runnable() {  

            public void run() {  
                try  
                {  
                    Log.v(TAG,"Going to sleep...");  
                    Thread.sleep(3000);  
                    Log.v(TAG,"Going to wake up...");  

                }  
                catch(Exception e)  
                {  
                    e.printStackTrace();  
                }  
            }  
        };  
        try  
        {  
            Thread t=new Thread(null,runnable);  
            t.start();  
            Intent i=new Intent(this,TabSample.class);  
                startActivity(i);  
        }  
        catch(Exception e)  
        {  

        }  

    }  
  }
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity
        android:name=".Welcome"
        android:label="Restaurant Application" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".TabSample"></
```

main.xml

```
   <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/imageView1"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
       android:src="@drawable/home" />
```

Comment: Main activity means is it TabSample

Answer (score 0):

use intent like this

```
Intent i=new Intent(Welcome.this,TabSample.class);  
startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this.

```
    public class Welcome extends Activity   
     {  
        private Runnable runnable;  
        private static final String TAG="Welcome";  

        /** Called when the activity is first created. */  
        @Override  
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)   
        {  
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
            setContentView(R.layout.main);  

            runnable=new Runnable() {  

                public void run() {  
                    try  
                    {  
                        Log.v(TAG,"Going to sleep...");  
                        Thread.sleep(3000);  
                        Log.v(TAG,"Going to wake up...");  

                       runOnUiThread(new Runnable() .
                         {

                         @Override
                         public void run() 
                         {
                            Intent i=new Intent(this,TabSample.class);  
                                           startActivity(i);  

                          }
            });


                    }  
                    catch(Exception e)  
                    {  
                        e.printStackTrace();  
                    }  
                }  
            };  
            try  
            {  
                Thread t=new Thread(null,runnable);  
                t.start();  

            }  
            catch(Exception e)  
            {  

            }  

        }  
      }
```

Because if you start Activity with parallel to threat then it will go forward without any delay and thread will run in background. so put you startactivity code in runonuithread. like above.

it may work for you.

Answer (score 0):

## Try this

```
 Thread thread = new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    try {


                        Thread.sleep(5000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Welcome.this, TabSample.class);
                    startActivity(intent);

                    finish();
                }
            };
            thread.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use timertask for showing the Welcome screen for some time
So here is how you go about it.

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
public class Welcome extends Activity {
private long splashDelay = 5000; //5 seconds

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    TimerTask task = new TimerTask()
    {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            finish();
            Intent mainIntent = new Intent().setClass(Welcome.this, TabSample.class);
            startActivity(mainIntent);
        }

    };

    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(task, splashDelay);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you only need to show the **Welcome** Activity for 5 seconds modify your thread. Remove and insert

```
Intent i=new Intent(this,TabSample.class);  
startActivity(i);
```

inside runnable.

Answer (score 0):

You Can only use a handler to do that . code will be like this

```
Runnable GotoMenu;
Handler CallMenu = new Handler();

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);       
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);

    GotoMenu = new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            CallMenu.removeCallbacks(GotoMenu);
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TabSample.class);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
    };
    CallMenu.postDelayed(GotoMenu, 2000);

}
```